# Create nested dictionary from a list of paths with each last item of path having some value other than an empty dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of paths like so:

```
paths = [
    "Properties/Static/E",
    "Properties/Static/Category1/A",
    "Properties/Static/Category2/Subcategory1/A",
    ...
    "Properties/Static/Category3/C"
]
```

And I want to create a nested dictionary of the data like so:

```
{
    "Properties": {
        "Static": {
            "E": *some_value*,
            "Category1": {
                "A": *some_value*,
                "Subcategory": {
                    "A": *some_value*
                }
            },
            ...
            "Category3": {
                "C": *some_value*
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where *some_value* will be calculated in a separate function.

I have tried a general algorithm - which I have seen from some other threads:

```
nested_dict = {}
for path in paths:                
    current_dict = nested_dict
    for level in path.split('/'):
        if level:                 
            current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(level, {})
```

But I cannot figure out how to set a the last item in the path - which will *always* be some value - to anything other then a dictionary. Running the above code outputs:

```
{
    "Properties": {
        "Static": {
            "E": {},
            "Category1": {
                "A": {},
                "Subcategory": {
                    "A": {}
                }
            },
            ...
            "Category3": {
                "C": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is not what I want to happen.

I tried for testing purposes - although not exactly pretty - something like this:

```
nested_dict = {}
for path in paths:                
    current_dict = nested_dict
    for i, level in enumerate(path.split('/')):
        if level:
            # Check if item is the last level, and set to a value
            # In this case I try setting to an empty string for testing purposes
            if i = len(path.split('/')) - 1:
                current_dict[level] = ""
            else:
                current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(level, {})
```

But I get the following error `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`.

I'm really at a lost with this. I cannot figure out how to adapt the code to resolve the error and I cannot figure out how to properly implement this algorithm. I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

I am using Python 2 if this helps (upgrading to version 3+ is impossible for me to do for this case).

Thank you.

Comment: Don't call your variables using built-in names (e.g. `dict`)

Comment: You just want the last value to be some default other than an empty `dict`?

Comment: @matszwecja Agreed, but this code isn't exactly what I'm using (my actual code has different variable names) just used that for simplicity to write.

Comment: @user2390182 Yes that is correct, the last item of the path should represent some value and not an empty dictionary but I can't seem to figure that part out